Need help to set COLD tier on Azure storage account
I have a question for you.
By reading Microsoft documentation I found out that there are 4 tiers of storage (hot, cool, cold and archive), while it's clear how to set the hot, cool and archive tier on a storage account I didn't really got how to set the cold tier.
So my question is, did you manage to set the cold tier on a storage account, and if so, how did you do it?
Thank you in advance.
(In case it could help my region is West EU, maybe it's yet to be available here?)
I tried to create a storage account, but I'm able to choose only among the "hot" and "cool" options.
I tried to look for something online but I didn't really seem to come across anything helpful.
I tried to navigate the menu of an already created hot storage account but neither this was a successful approach.

"I tried to look for something online but I didn't really seem to come across anything helpful." - May I ask exactly what web-search queries you were using? I was able to find the relevant pages in MS' Azure docs instantly.

Storage accounts themselves don't have a tier, only their blobs do. The setting you're looking at controls the default storage tier for all new blobs in that account.
From the docs (emphasis mine):

Storage accounts have a default access tier setting that indicates the online tier in which a new blob is created. The default access tier setting can be set to either hot or cool. Users can override the default setting for an individual blob when uploading the blob or changing its tier.



So my question is, did you manage to set the cold tier on a storage account, and if so, how did you do it?

When uploading a new blob, the storage-account's default tier will be used unless you override it with the x-ms-access-tier header.
If you want to move all blobs in a storage-account to the Cold or Archive tiers, then you accomplish that by either:

For each blob, make a PUT Set-Blob-Tier request to Azure. You can also make a batch request.
Setting a lifecycle policy on the storage-account which will automatically change the tier of blobs based on their age and time-since-last-accessed.

